# Display by tag from different post types

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, tags

I'm trying to display posts within the WP loop and am able to successfully do so with `<?php query_posts('tag_id=10'); ?>` Here the loop will display all posts with the tag ID of 10, but I'd also like the loop to display posts from within a Custom Post type by the same tag.

I'm able to successfully display posts with tag_id=10 that originate from a custom post type using `<?php query_posts('tag_id=10&post_type=videos'); ?>`

But how can I merge the two?

I gave this a shot: `<?php query_posts('tag_id=10', 'tag_id=10&post_type=videos'); ?>` but that had no effect (well actually it broke everything!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may i suggest you use instead get_posts()?

**example**

```
$args_t10 = array(
  'tag_id' => 10,
);
$postslist_t10 = get_posts( $args_t10 ); ?>

$args_t10_v = array(
   'tag_id' => 10,
   'post_type' => 'videos'
);
$postslist_t10_v = get_posts( $args_t10_v );
```

you then can merge and filter the duplicates

```
$postmixed = array_merge($postslist_t10, $postslist_t10_v);
$uniqueposts = array_unique(postmixed);
```

### reference

**wp**: [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)

**php**: [array-unique()](http://pt2.php.net/array_unique)  , [array_merge](http://pt2.php.net/array_merge)